# angular/ngbmodal: backdropClass doesnt work

Tags: angular, bootstrap-ui

I am trying to change background color of ngbmodal dialog to blue using **backdropClass** . It doesn't work, why?

my code is:

*** component call:**

```
let options: NgbModalOptions = {
        size: 'sm',
        backdrop:'static',
        backdropClass: "light-blue-backdrop"
      };

      var res = this.modalService.open(content, options);
```

***html component:**

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

*** css classes:**

```
.dark-modal .modal-content {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }

.dark-modal .close {
    color: white;
}

.light-blue-backdrop {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

The image you see appears background in black instead of blue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a global style (styles folder) with a background definition of a backdrop. Backdrops of [ng-bootstrap modals](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) are injected into body tag.

Don't change app ViewEncapsulation, particularly for app component... It's gonna cause you a lot of problems.

Comment: the url you wrote is bad. As you said ViewEncapsulation is not the solution because broke the rest flex styles I had in my web. please could you write the valid url please?

Answer (score 0):

You need use ViewEncapsulation.None(*)

In your component

```
import { Component,ViewEncapsulation  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, //<--this line
  ...
})
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4wuam?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

(*)Be carefull, ViewEncapsulation.None, make that all the .css in your component propagate to all the application, so if you has in .css some like

```
h1{color:red}
```

All yours h1 in the application becomes color red. To avoid it you can enclose all your component in a div with a class and write your .css like

```
.mycomponent.h1{color:red}
```

Comment: using ViewEncapsulation.None was working but .... Broke other styles of my web which was working, like animation effects with angular.